# What the ☺♣○♥ is that?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

This is some text

> xn--nvg19c64gfb7a3ei68ejao7bxa99alb3aq0fsa

What does it signify?

Comment: OP, please add some examples.

Comment: @TheBitByte: Examples? Of what?

Comment: @Deusovi Of some random/example text encoded using the same encoding method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's

> [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) for ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕, the first few characters of one form of Extended ASCII (as well as the first few alt codes in some forms of Windows).